# Spring Boot Cucumber Java 8 Testing ApplicationOnReady Event

Tags: spring-boot, mockito, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

I have a reporting application that generates a report on ApplicationReadyEvent. I am trying to write cucumber tests for it but as the application event is fired even before my feature is executed , i am not sure what is the right way to test it. Can i control the event during testing ?

```
 @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    private void generateAccuracyAnalysisReport() throws IOException
    {
//some Logic
}
```

Cucumber Classes :

```
@SpringBootTest
@CucumberContextConfiguration
@ActiveProfiles("junit")
public class CucumberConfiguration
{
}
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(plugin = "pretty", features = "src/test/resources/cucumber/features")
public class CucumberFullIntegrationTest
{
}
```

Step Definition:

```
public class ReportStepDefs implements En {

    public ReportStepDefs() {
        When("^System sends an application event to generate report$", () -> {
        });
        Then("^Report should be generated successfully\\.$", () -> {


        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your Cucumber tests involve Spring life-cycle you can not use `cucumber-spring`. Rather you have to use something like Springs [`ApplicationContextRunner`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/context/runner/ApplicationContextRunner.html) to, configure, run and verify something about your application as part of each scenario.

```java
// Given
ApplicationContextRunner contextRunner = new ApplicationContextRunner();
        
// When
contextRunner.withConfiguration(AutoConfigurations.of(...);

// Then
contextRunner.run(context -> assertThat(context).... /* something */ );

// Or assert something external to the application context.
```

Though it sounds like your application is doing something once and then exits. If so you should be using the [`CommandLineRunner`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/CommandLineRunner.html) instead of `ApplicationReadyEvent` in a web application. This *is* testable with `cucumber-spring`.

```java
@RequiredArsConstructor
public class StepDefinitions {
  
  final MyCommandLineRunner commandLineRunner;

  @When(....)
  public void something() {
    commandLineRunner.run("input.txt", "input2.txt");
  }

  @Then(....)
  public void assertSomething() {
    // check if report was generated
  }
}
```